# Silverlight avoid requesting an event twice

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I have a Control say for ex a `Submit` button if user clicks the button twice or more continuously then user receiving same message / same operation taking place twice or more.

I need to avoid this situation.

thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to detect the button click event either in the code behind of the view (or ViewModel if using the MVVM pattern) and disable the button.  Now I take it that your submit button is firing off some kind of asynchronous operation.  Once the asynchronous operation has successfully completed you will probably need to enable the button so that it is available again.

Comment: Yes i know this way... and also i'm using one private boolean variable  which will set false at the time of submit button and will be set to true at the completed event...Is there is any other way or good practice to do?

Comment: There is no "magic" out of the box solution.  I think the approach suggested here is simple and works.

Answer (score -1):

Shankar, if you want to avoid clicking on button, you should disable it. If you can give more details about what exactly you are trying to do, more details can be given.

Comment: if user enters details and clicks submit button twice the same submit event have been triggered! this is my issue... i need to avoid this... Is that clear to you...

Comment: You should disable the button until some processing is complete that you want to do after click on button and then re-enable it.

Comment: I think I was trying to explain the same thing, Myles has explained it better.